# fetching images from Amazon s3 gives CORS error. (Chrome issue)

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to fetch images from Amazon s3 with these CORS config:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

and the error I receive is :

```
Image from origin 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin     Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I receive this error in Chrome but not in Firefox.
I've tried browsing but haven't found a solution.
Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you putting these cors rules?

Comment: Having the same problem.  It's with the caching in chrome, the access control headers are never cached correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I keep my eyes on AWS questions, and I see this quite a bit  The problem with this question (and those like it) is that it only exposes half of the equation (the CORS configuration) to the community.  The "C" in [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) certainly isn't satisfied.

The missing half of the equation is how you're trying to access the resource on the front end.  Specifically, the **request headers** that are sent are critical.

- Are you using `fetch`?  `canvas`?  Amazon SDK?  Something like
  [domtoimage](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)?
- Have you captured the request headers for the
  failing request?

  - If so, *why aren't they in the question?*

---

**CORS Basics**

If you don't send an `origin` request header, you're not going to get CORS response headers back.  If you do send an `origin` header, and the origin is allowed, you should get CORS headers back.  It's that simple.

So a missing `origin` header should be the first thing you rule out.  Are you absolutely sure you're sending an `origin` header?  More often, is the library you're using sending one?  If you dig a little deeper, the real question may be "why isn't an `origin` header present on my request?"

*Side Note:* You can use a browser extension like [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) to remove the `origin` header from all outgoing requests, and marvel at all the stuff that breaks.

---

**Works in x, but not y**

Back to my "post your request headers" soapbox - If Chrome and Firefox are acting differently, have you verified that each is sending the same set of headers?

Several headers are set for you by the browser, and browser implementations [may make different choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512331/chrome-adding-origin-header-to-same-origin-request) regarding which headers to send when.

Comment: Hm - didn't know that - good to know, though.  I wound up getting it to work by using `mode: 'no-cors'`

Comment: I'll leave this open a bit - and likely accept this answer for the bounty.  Thanks a ton!